# Security implications of remember me cookies? (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, security, authentication

I am thinking about adding remember me functionality (following this excellent [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/274-remember-me-reset-password)), however I am a little concerned about security.

What happens if someone gets hold of a cookie from another user, will that boil down to them having access to all their account as they'll essentially be logged in? (And what are the chances of users cookies being stolen?)

Would it be better to have a normal session for the User (that ends when they close the browser) and the cookie only remembers that user.id but does **not** log them back in when they return, just auto fills the username (or email) part of the log-in form so they only need to enter their password to continue.

This seems more secure to me, but maybe I am being a little too paranoid?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely secure system will be unusable. System with very good usability usually not very secure.

"Remember me" is classic usability feature, which decreases security.

In the case, if you do financial transactions, I would rather not implement this feature (because security is more important).

In the case, if you do a website where you can post a kitten photos, I think it's ok.

Also, you can always make time limited cookies, so your "remember me" feature will remember you not more than a day. This will boost usability, but will keep system reasonably secure.

Comment: and you may require reauthentication on password change or other critical operation. that will prevent attacker from stealing account forever

Comment: Also regenerate remember me cookie after making use of it... Make it random not crypto... And check for it's freshness... IMPLICITLY (do not use cookie expiry attribute, hold cookie validity time server side).

Comment: Fatfredyy, your last comment was key to me. Would you say that a "pretty paranoid" app should store expiration time in the db rather than in `cookies.signed[:remember_created_at]`?